# How to read user email from Azure Devops Extension azure-devops-extension-api/Profile

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-boards

Below is code snippet

```
import { ProfileRestClient} from "azure-devops-extension-api/Profile";
const profile_client = await getClient(ProfileRestClient);
const profile_data =await profile_client.getProfile('me');
```

when i tried this i'm getting this(locationUrl is avaiable i checked with restapi) :

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'locationUrl')
    at https://cdn.vsassets.io/ext/ms.vss-features/ext-services-content/ms.vss-features.ext-services-content.es6.SL9RycQIREuTlVnV.min.js:1:13179
```

**can you suggest any other alternative approaches i want read user email using user id**